# Shortcut to Tabor Monastery of the Transfiguration

Tags: georgia-country, tbilisi

In Tbilisi, I want to visit the Tabor Monastery of the Transfiguration for the views to the castle and the city.

The road to the monastery winds its way through the hills for 2.7km or 42min walking from the Sulfur Baths, even though the monastery is only about 300m away as the crow flies.

Is there a walking track or other shortcut from the Sulfur Baths to the monastery? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to OpenStreetmap, there is indeed a path leading to the monastery:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=graphhopper_foot&route=41.68757%2C44.81074%3B41.68600%2C44.81300#map=16/41.6866/44.8122

[image: route]